# Problem deploying Firebase Functions from AWS Code Build

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm having a difficulty deploying Firebase functions from CI (namely AWS CodeBuild) due to unknown reasons.

The `firebase deploy` command is invoked with `--token` argument, so it doesn't seem like an authentication issue, in fact, hosting files are being deployed without any issues.

One suspicion I have is that when I run this locally, it works like a charm, and the obvious difference is the part that says `package . (263 B) for uploading` because when I run it locally, it has way more than 263-bytes (local says `69.23 MB`).  Also, because it runs locally without any issues, I don't think there is any issue with `firebase.json` is configured incorrectly.

Has anyone ran into a similar issue?

```sh
$ export DOTENV_RUNTIME=qa1 && cross-env NODE_ENV=production firebase deploy --only hosting,functions --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN

...
i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing . directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged . (263 B) for uploading
✔  functions: . folder uploaded successfully
i  hosting[project-xyz]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[project-xyz]: found 47 files in public
✔  hosting[project-xyz]: file upload complete
i  functions: updating Node.js 12 function nextServer(us-central1)...
⚠  functions[nextServer(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Build failed: function.js does not exist; Error ID: 7485c5b6


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    nextServer


To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only "functions:nextServer"


To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Here are the contents of some of the relevant configuration files:

**firebase.json**

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "nextServer"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      ".git/**",
      ".firebase/**",
      ".firebaserc",
      "**/node_modules/**",
      "**/public/**",
      "**/src/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  ...
  "main": "dist/server/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  ...
}
```

Here's the root directory structure.

```sh
$ tree -v -L 1 -a
.
├── .firebase
├── .firebaserc
├── .git
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
├── dist
├── firebase.json
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── public
├── src
└── yarn.lock
```

Comment: Can you share what your project root directory looks like?

Comment: @nVitius Thanks for your comment. Added the root directory structure.

Comment: Where do you define your functions? Your firebase config is set up to use `.` directory for the functions, but there is no `index.js`. I believe this might be causing the issue.

Comment: @nVitius Thanks for your comment. The functions are defined in `dist/server/index.js` as specified in `package.json`'s `main` directive. Given your input, I've tried relocating index.js to the root, but no difference made and packaged size still seems to be very small. Besides, I think deploy is picking up that file without issues as the log mentions it: `updating Node.js 12 function nextServer(us-central1).` ( `nextServer` is one of the functions declared in `dist/server/index.js`)

Answer (score 1):

I went through the firebase-tools source code and found that when using AWS Code Build, the source is downloaded and built under `/codebuild/output/src123456789/src/github.com/...`. If you ignore `**/src/**`, no files would be targeted for deploy because the path name contains `src`.  This also answers why the packaged size was so small.

Thanks to @nVitius for raising questions.